# variable.length is undefined when length = 1

Tags: javascript

I am using js to alert the length of a variable(field) but is crushing when my field.length is supposed to be equal to 1.

When field.length is greater than 1 everything works fine. Any ideas?

This is the HTML code

```
<form>
<someloop>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mark" value="#recID#">
</someloop>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick="dlte(mark);" >Delete</button>
</form>
```

JS Code:

```
function dlte(field){
        alert(field.length);
    }
```

Comment: You use a variable `mark` there in the inline JavaScript. What's its content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found for my issue

```
function(filed){
 'var $srt = $(field); 
  alert($srt.length);' 
}
```

Also, a note to @DaHaka and @Steve H.

You recommended that I had to add single quotes around my varibale (`'mark'`) but this ended up braking my code for some reason. When I took them off the code started working as I wanted it. Regardless of that, thanks for the help and recommendations!! :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass references of DOM nodes as you are attempting in your onClick handler.

Try:

```
onclick="dlte('mark');"
```

and the function:

```
function dlte(field) {
    var nodes= document.getElementsByName(field);
    alert(nodes[0].length);
}
```

Comment: the alert is returning undefined again. If I remove the `[0]` is returning 0 where it was supposed to be 1

Comment: @GeoNicolaidis You're right , in your case , you must use `getElementsByName` without `nodes` . Take a look at my example

Comment: Ya, @DaHaKa my bad- I assumed he had added a property to the DOM node.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="dlte('mark')" >Delete</button>    

function dlte(field){
    alert(document.getElementsByName(field).length);
}
```

If your `mark` name is name of html element you should use `getElementsByName` property to get length

Comment: your's still outputs 0. What I don't get is when I have length > than 1 it outputs everything ok but when my length = 1 it outputs 0 ...

Comment: When you have only one element checkbox with attr (name="mark") it will alert 1. Test it out correctly

Comment: @GeoNicolaidis It will alert 0 when you have no checkbox with attr (name="mark")

Comment: but I do have a checkbox named "mark". I found the solution btw :) 'var $srt = $(field); alert($srt.length);' This outputs 1

Comment: @GeoNicolaidis jQuery is nice solution , but to be aware of marked script working , just create new html doc and test it out , I've tested too , its working how expected :)